# R - auto-fit excel column widths across multiple sheets at once

Tags: r, excel, xlsx, column-width, openxlsx

Suppose I have datatables that I want to export to multiple worksheets of an Excel file. I did it in this way using `openxlsx` package:

```
 list_of_sheets <- list("apple" = apple, 
                        "avocado" = avocado,
                        "banana" = banana)
 write.xlsx(list_of_sheets, file = "fruits.xlsx"))
```

Some of my rows in multiple columns on different sheets have a very long length, so I want to set the auto-fit of the column width.

How do I **autofit the column width for all column in all sheets** of my Excel book, using `openxlsx`?

I tried the following code:

```
fruits <- loadWorkbook("fruits.xlsx"))
 for(curr_sheet in names(fruits)){
   setColWidths(fruits, sheet = curr_sheet, cols = 1:ncol(curr_sheet), widths = "auto")
   saveWorkbook(fruits, "fruits.xlsx"), overwrite = TRUE)
 }
```

but I had the following error:

```
Error in 1:ncol(curr_sheet) : argument of length 0
```

How can I do this? Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: `curr_sheet` is a character string, it has no colums. You need the dataframe corresponding to `curr_sheet`. I don't know, but maybe `1:ncol(fruits[[curr_sheet]])`